# Adding 2 components in my app.component.ts

Tags: angular

In my app.component I would like to display 2 different components. One is a list of courses the other a list of authors.

I ended up with below, individually they work, so coursescomponent commented out the authors component will display.

How do I get both to display?

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorsComponent} from './authors.component'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<h1>My first Angular2 App</h1><courses></courses>',
directives: [CoursesComponent],

})

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',

template: '<authors></authors>',
directives: [AuthorsComponent]

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Have you gone through the Heroes tutorial?

Comment: The package name was never `angular2/core`; it's normally `@angular/core`.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi it was `angular2/core` in beta

Comment: Its to old version angular2/core i thing so angular 2 rc -beta old release

Comment: thanks aware that it is the rc old release, not the answer to my question though. Will look athe the Heroes tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
import {AuthorsComponent} from './authors.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My first Angular2 App</h1><courses></courses> <authors></authors>',
  directives: [CoursesComponent, AuthorsComponent],
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

btw, update your code based-on latest Angular version as this tutorial

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/learning-angular.html

include your directives, pipe and other components to `declarations` array.

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent/* other pipe, directive, component */ ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: @echonax i know, maybe people like him need a tutorial to find out the stable version to use.